# I'm struggeling to manipulate a vector

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, integer, gsub

I have scraped prices from a site and now i want to remove the currency, the space between the currency and the price and convert it as integer.
My vector looks like this:

```
> dput(vec_tectake)
c("CHF 99.00", "CHF 469.00", "CHF 179.00", "CHF 181.00", "CHF 21.90", 
"CHF 256.00", "CHF 152.00", "CHF 167.00", "CHF 154.00", "CHF 314.00", 
"CHF 269.00", "CHF 105.00", "CHF 34.00", "CHF 28.00", "CHF 154.00", 
"CHF 56.00", "CHF 62.00", "CHF 82.00", "CHF 33.90", "CHF 60.00", 
"CHF 33.00", "CHF 44.00", "CHF 32.00", "Error in open.connection(x, \"rb\") : HTTP error 404.\n", 
"CHF 114.00", "CHF 52.00", "CHF 33.00", "CHF 59.90", "CHF 48.00", 
"Error in open.connection(x, \"rb\") : HTTP error 404.\n", "Error in open.connection(x, \"rb\") : HTTP error 404.\n", 
"CHF 219.00", "CHF 834.00", "CHF 899.00", "CHF 299.00", "CHF 154.00", 
"CHF 112.00", "CHF 170.00", "Error in open.connection(x, \"rb\") : HTTP error 404.\n", 
"Error in open.connection(x, \"rb\") : HTTP error 404.\n", "CHF 67.00", 
"CHF 47.00", "CHF 49.00", "CHF 77.00", "Error in open.connection(x, \"rb\") : HTTP error 404.\n", 
"Error in open.connection(x, \"rb\") : HTTP error 404.\n", "CHF 50.00", 
"CHF 38.00", "CHF 114.00", "CHF 45.00", "CHF 219.00", "CHF 94.00", 
"CHF 155.00", "CHF 98.00", "Error in open.connection(x, \"rb\") : HTTP error 404.\n", 
"CHF 469.00", "CHF 29.00", "CHF 81.00", "CHF 64.00", "CHF 83.00", 
"CHF 154.00", "CHF 164.00", "CHF 144.00", "CHF 69.00")
```

as you can see i already managed to remove the currency with

```
vec_tectake<-gsub("CHF", "", vec_tectake)
```

but now if i try to remove the blank space with

```
vec_tectake<-gsub(" ","", vec_tectake)
```

it doesen't work.
Also converting it to a integer with "as.integer()" gives me just the error message "Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion", and all the prices turn into NA's.

Edit: If i try it out with a vector like

```
vec1<-c("CHF 90.00", "CHF 3.00", "CHF 5.00")
```

everything works just fine.

Comment: I used vector `vec1<-c("CHF 90.00", "CHF 3.00", "CHF 5.00", 'Errorinopen.connection(x,\"rb\"):HTTPerror404.')` and used your code, the output was `[1] "90.00"                                          "3.00"                                          
[3] "5.00"                                           "Errorinopen.connection(x,\"rb\"):HTTPerror404."`. Is this your expected output?

Comment: Hey Nad, thanks for your quick response. Yes, that's what i want to achieve in a first step. I also get these results if i try it with this example vector, but if I try it with my real dataset, only the step with removing the "CHF" works. Removing the blank space somehow doesn't seem to work and also convert it to integer fails.

Comment: It would be helpful if your could provide your real dataset using `dput(x)`.

Comment: Ok, good idea. I replaced the code in my original question with the dput output.
Edit: If I just copy the code from the dput back into my R, it seems to work now...

Comment: It worked fine with your real data. What is the error you are encountering?

Comment: Yes, now when I copy the data from the dput back into my R it seems to work as well...
but no idea why